# can''t connect to oracle database in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, oracle

my version of node.js is 0.10.4 and my version of Os is Centos 5.9 and oracle is 11gR2 .
when i want to connect to oracle with node.js , i use this article on this link https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle , when i want to install db-oracle with **npm install db-oracle**, the error in below is shown :

```
npm install db-oracle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/db-oracle
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/db-oracle

> db-oracle@0.2.3 install /opt/instantclient/node_modules/db-oracle

> node-waf configure build
sh: node-waf: command not found
> db-oracle@0.2.3 preuninstall /opt/instantclient/node_modules/db-oracle
> rm -rf build/*

npm ERR! weird error 127
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

can any one help me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [During npm install socket.io I get error 127, node-waf command not found. How to solve it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778332/during-npm-install-socket-io-i-get-error-127-node-waf-command-not-found-how-to)

Comment: no , i am sorry . it is about socket.io but my problem is about node-waf and node-db-oracle

Comment: It is about missing node-waf, read the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few pointers:

https://github.com/mariano/node-db-oracle/issues/53

> Node.js does not support node-waf anymore and therefore this project needs to be update. To install this anyways, 1)Install a lower
>   version of node.js. I noticed this project has not been updated ina
>   about a years so I selected node.js v0.6.4 which came out a year ago.
>   2) re-run installation 3) now that you have the package installed you
>   may upgrade node.js (cross your fingers that it works or you might
>   have to go back down to a lower version. You'll run into problems if
>   you try to reinstall db-oracle).

Comment: i read this issue , but i want to use node.js 0.10.4 ..... the 0.6.4 version is not ok for me

Comment: And maybe with the downgrade node, install module, upgrade node scenario?

Comment: @saeed.sh Then you'll need to find [another package for Oracle](https://npmjs.org/search?q=oracle). Or possibly [fork `node-db-oracle`](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) or [start your own package](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and [publish it](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-publish.html). But, `db-oracle` simply hasn't been maintained and isn't compatible with 0.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect to oracle db from node, let me recommend you to use [node-oracle](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle) module.

To install, follow the procedure described in the module.

I did not have any issues with this module on OSX and RHEL 6.