# Cannot start node site with npm start

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mozilla, persona

I am trying to get a simple [site](https://github.com/mozilla/123done) using Mozilla Persona installed locally on ubuntu 12.04.  However, I ran into problems getting it to install and run.  I get an error message about node-waf not found if I am using the latest version of nodejs (0.10.24) installed from source.

Looking into the issue I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486055/3188582) that the node-waf function was removed in version 0.9.1.  So I uninstalled 0.10.24 and installed 0.9.0.  Now I can `npm install` without error but run into the follow error when I `npm start`:

```
> 123done@0.0.1 start /home/user3188582/123done
> node server.js


module.js:485
  process.dlopen(filename, module.exports);
          ^
Error: Module version mismatch, refusing to load.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user3188582/123done/node_modules/client-sessions/node_modules/node-proxy/lib/node-proxy.js:1:90)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
npm ERR! 123done@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 123done@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the 123done package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 123done
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-58-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user3188582/123done
npm ERR! node -v v0.9.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.44
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! stack Error: 123done@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! stack `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:56:20)
npm ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
npm ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:674:10)
npm ERR! stack     at process.startup.processMakeCallback.process._makeCallback (node.js:238:20)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user3188582/123done/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The contents of npm-debug.log are:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.1.44
3 info using node@v0.9.0
4 verbose config file /home/user3188582/.npmrc
5 verbose config file /usr/local/etc/npmrc
6 verbose config file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
7 verbose read json /home/user3188582/123done/package.json
8 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
9 info prestart 123done@0.0.1
10 info start 123done@0.0.1
11 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
12 silly exec sh "-c" "node server.js"
13 silly sh,-c,node server.js,/home/user3188582/123done spawning
14 info 123done@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
15 error 123done@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
15 error `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1
16 error Failed at the 123done@0.0.1 start script.
16 error This is most likely a problem with the 123done package,
16 error not with npm itself.
16 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
16 error     node server.js
16 error You can get their info via:
16 error     npm owner ls 123done
16 error There is likely additional logging output above.
17 error System Linux 3.2.0-58-generic
18 error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error cwd /home/user3188582/123done
20 error node -v v0.9.0
21 error npm -v 1.1.44
22 error code ELIFECYCLE
23 error stack Error: 123done@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
23 error stack `sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1
23 error stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:56:20)
23 error stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
23 error stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:674:10)
23 error stack     at process.startup.processMakeCallback.process._makeCallback (node.js:238:20)
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm fairly new with node so I haven't the slightest idea what problem this error indicates.  Anyone have suggestions for getting `npm start` to work correctly?

Comment: node 0.9 is a development branch of 0.10, I would avoid using that. On my local machine (Ubuntu 12.04), I can `npm install` 123done just fine using node 0.10.24.

Comment: @FrancoisMarier Thanks!  After completely removing node and installing 0.10.24 I deleted the 123done repo and cloned again.  Now I am able to `npm install` and `npm start` without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

> After completely removing node and installing 0.10.24 I deleted the 123done repo and cloned again. Now I am able to npm install and npm start without any issue